# Multiple inputs into new prompt & Powershell -run as and -nonewwindow issue

Tags: powershell, input, cmd, admin, elevated-privileges

Here is what I currently do, file 1:

```
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c cd C:\ && DiskZero.cmd'-Verb runas"
```

And file 2 "DiskZero.cmd":

```
@echo off
(echo rescan
echo sel disk 1
echo cle all
echo cre part prim
echo for fs=ntfs quick label=Intenso
echo assign letter=E
)  | diskpart
pause
```

It works as intended, however, there is two files, what I want to do is make it so there's only one file.

I can't manage to find how to input multiple lines of code into a new elevated command prompt with only one script, so instead I'm trying to do it with powershell:

`start cmd -nonewwindow` works

`start cmd -ver runas` works

however `start cmd -nonewwindow -ver runas` doesn't work

What I was hoping to do was this in powershell:

```
start cmd -nonewwindow -ver runas
@echo off
(echo rescan
echo sel disk 1
echo cle all
echo cre part prim
echo for fs=ntfs quick label=Intenso
echo assign letter=E
)  | diskpart
pause
```

Can anyone help me solve the `start cmd -nonewwindow -ver runas` issue **OR** input multiple lines of code into a new elevated command prompt with only one file, please?

Comment: Try using the builtin PowerShell functions. To discover them use: Get-Command \*partition\*

Comment: @RetiredGeek I just tried but PowerShell tells me this command doesn't exist

Comment: Fixed, editor killed the asterisks had to escape them with backslash.

Comment: @RetiredGeek Oh okay, I just tried and now it indeed works; however, I thought it was something that'll help the PowerShell issue but "Get-Command *partition*" is a partition management command? ; so I'm not really sure why you recommended me this command ahah

Comment: They're cmdlets that are the equivalent to the legacy commands of cmd.exe, diskpart: stands for *disk **partition***. Hence the recommendation to stick with native powershell cmdlets. What you most likely need, is the *volume* cmdlets, so you'd need to query for those instead.

Comment: I know what diskpart stands for haha, I already know how to use it as I use it everyday; I'm not really sure I want to learn how to use PowerShell's equivalent of DiskPart though; not only would this not solve my current problem, this would also force me to spend time learning it.

I'd like to just be able to continue to use DiskPart, I just need help for the start command, thanks tho :)!

Comment: No worries, was just trying to answer your question of why that was recommended. Back to your original question, you mention  running lines of code in a new elevated cmd.exe instance, but you are trying to use the `-NoNewWindow` parameter. So which one is it? A new instance, or the same console window?

Comment: Are you just looking to run those commands in cmd.exe's context?

Comment: Yes, I might have badly explained sorry English isn't my main language; I actually tried 2 things: The first one was writing everything in a batch file, I start by using the powershell command in the batch file to create a new elevated command prompt window, then I tried to make it so the diskpart commands are inputed in the new elevated window; but I wasn't able to input new command in a new window by using only batch file.

Comment: So now the second thing: I'm trying using the start command in powershell, to elevate a cmd prompt inside powershell, and then input the diskpart script in the admin cmd prompt opened inside the powershell window. Sorry if you still don't understand what I'm trying to say ahah @AbrahamZinala

Comment: Why do you need to run the commands separately? Are you not already running the first execution as admin? You should be able to just use the commands as-is without having to open a new elevated instance.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I'm not sure what you mean by running the command separately; I want to run all the commands in the same cmd prompt, but for that I need the command prompt to be admin by using the `powershell start cmd -verb runas` command

Comment: So you want to combine file 2 with file 1? Are you running file 1 from a batch file?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yep, both are .cmd batch files and I want to combine them to have only one file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone help me solve the start `cmd -nonewwindow -verb runas` issue

Unfortunately, there is *no* solution: **Windows fundamentally does not allow you to run an *elevated* process (run as admin, requested with `-Verb RunAs`) directly in a *non-elevated* process' console window** - that is why [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) *syntactically* prevents combining `-NoNewWindow` with `-Verb RunAs`.

> OR input multiple lines of code into a new elevated command prompt with only one file, please?

While there is a solution, it'll be **hard to maintain**:

You can **pass the lines of your second batch file** (the one you want to eliminate) **to `cmd /c` on a *single* line, *joined with `&`***:

- Note: To facilitate side effect-free experimentation, the original `diskpart` command was replaced with `findstr -n .`, which merely *prints* the lines received via stdin, preceded by their line number.

```
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd '/c cd C:\ && (echo rescan&echo sel disk 1&echo cle all&echo cre part prim&echo for fs=ntfs quick label=Intenso&echo assign letter=E) | findstr -n .&pause'"
```

<sup>That no space char. precedes each `&` is deliberate, because trailing whitespace in `echo` commands is significant, i.e. it becomes part of the output; however, it should be fine to place a space char. *after* each `&` (as well as before, if the preceding command ignores trailing whitespace).</sup>

A **better solution is to create a *temporary* helper batch file from your batch file**, pass its path to the PowerShell command, and delete it afterwards:

```
@echo off

:: Determine the path for a temporary batch file...
:: Note: %~snx0 uses the short (8.3) name of the batch file, so as
::       to ensure that the temp. file path has no spaces, which 
::       obviates the need for complex double-quoting later.
set "tmpBatchFile=%TEMP%\~%~snx0"

:: ... and fill it with the desired commands.
:: Note how metacharacters - ( ) | ... - must be ^-escaped.
(
echo @echo off
echo ^(echo rescan
echo echo sel disk 1
echo echo cle all
echo echo cre part prim
echo echo for fs=ntfs quick label=Intenso
echo echo assign letter=E
echo ^) ^| findstr -n .
echo pause
) > "%tmpBatchFile%"

:: Now you can let the elevated cmd.exe process that PowerShell launches
:: execute the temp. batch file.
:: Note: -Wait ensures that the PowerShell call blocks until the elevated 
::       cmd.exe window closes.
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs cmd '/c cd C:\ & %tmpBatchFile%'"

:: Delete the temp. batch file.
:: Note: If you do NOT use -Wait above, you'll have to defer deleting
::       the batch file until after the elevated cmd.exe window closes,
::       which you'll have to do manually.
del "%tmpBatchFile%"
```

Comment: I found the source of the problem! It seems like PowerShell or DiskPart wasn't happy with how I named my file; I named it "test diskpart.cmd" and I guess they don't like spaces so they were looking for a file only called "test.cmd"; I removed the space and now everything works as intended, thanks again! I'll make sure to come upvote your answer once I'll have enough reputation!

Comment: Good to know, @OUTEIRALDIASEsteban, my pleasure, and thanks for intent to up-vote when possible. I've updated the answer to use the short (8.3) name of the batch file to form the temporary file path, which should also make it work if the batch file name has spaces in it. The alternative would be to use embedded `"..."` quoting around `%tmpBatchFile%` inside the `cmd.exe` command nested inside the PowerShell command, but that gets messy.